# Get a website's host machine's OS/server software without access to the server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, web

Is there a good methodology to find the operating system and server software that is being used on a served website that you don't have SSH access to? What I'm doing right now is looking at TCP/IP headers in a browser development window. Also, purposely going to 404s, but I find that a lot of server information is taken out of any messages that are displayed.

Comment: What Arul and HopelessN00b said.  Just be aware that portscanning a server that isn't yours is generally considered a hostile act, and the remote router might block you for it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to know this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm trying to take over the world.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option, without SSH access [would be nmap's OS detection](http://nmap.org/book/man.html).

It's not going to be totally reliable, but it's probably better than nothing, which seems to be your other option.  [Here's a page with a little run down on how the OS detection work](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-determine-os-of-the-remote-computer)s, which should give you an idea of its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nmap as mentioned by the previous response.

```
sudo nmap -sV -T4 -O -F --version-light <your_server>
```

**NOTE**: If you run a nmap against a server that you don't own, prepare to explain when a call from network security admin asking you what are you trying to do. In other words, don't do it if it is not your server.